# Vue/Vuex retains data from previous user

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've created a Vue application using vue-router and vuex. The problem I am facing with this application is that, when A user logs out and another user logs in, the second user still sees data of the previous user. After refreshing the page, API method gets called and new data loads. But, if the use doesn't reload the page, API doesn't get called. I'm using **Vue 3**. Is there any solution to stop Vue/Vuex from retaining previous data?

my code structure is this:

```
data() {
    return {
        data: []
    }
},
created() {
    this.fetchData();
},
methods: {
    async fetchData() {
        try {
            this.data = await this.$store.dispatch('dash/getUserData');
        } catch(error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
     }
}
```

And, within action part of the vuex store

```
async getUserData(context) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if (!res.ok) {
       // error handling
    }
    const data = await res.json();
    context.commit('setUserData', data);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Add a logout method to clear the user data from Vuex.

Comment: I've added one already. In which, I clear the data that from browser. Still vuex stores the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer to this problem. It's not the best, but works tho. Here's is the link to the whole thread:
 `https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1118`
It says, we can create a custom function, to reset the state(s) of the module(s) using mutations, which then should be called to every time a user logs out.